# Android , create notification code doing nothing

Tags: android

Unable to create notification, I have checked several articles code samples look same as mine. Please check the below code and where I am doing the mistake.

Below I have pasted 2 classes. MainActivity class, where one button click should create notification. Second class, where notification is created.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    NotificationBuilder nB=new NotificationBuilder();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToSecondActivity();
                nB.createNotify();
            }

        });


    }

    private void goToSecondActivity() {


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}


**Second class**

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class NotificationBuilder extends AppCompatActivity {

    void createNotify() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Tried with noughat and Kitkat Apis level.
Tried using another phone, but similar results

Answer (score 0):

`NotificationBuilder nB=new NotificationBuilder();`

You're essentially never supposed to create an `Activity` like this. It means several required internal components will not be properly initialized.

This means that all the instances of `this` in `createNotify` do not work as expected. The context needs to be `MainActivity` and not your builder class.

Stop extending `NotificationBuilder` to an `Activity` and pass the correct `Context` as a parameter to `createNotify`. Replacing most calls of `this` with the context should fix your code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I'm unable to understand, could you please make some edit on my code.